# Trying to optimize intersection of n ranges but haven't came up with a solution yet?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, optimization

here is my version of code i need to check every range and the ranges are in 10^9 limit

```
p = []
count = 0
n = int(input())
for i in range(n):
    a = list(map(int,input().split()))
    p.append(a)
for i in range(n):    
    for j in range(n):
            if range(max(p[i][0], p[j][0]), min(p[i][-1], p[j][-1])+1):
                count+=1
print(count-n)
```

I guess this answer is slow because of O(n^2).
This code takes n (start and end) of ranges and returns the total number of intersection possible

Comment: If you do not have an actual programming problem, but you want your code to be reviewed, you should post on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I'm new to the programming world. Thanks for enlightening me.

Comment: The purpose of that code is not clear. Please clarify.

Comment: Sir this takes  n ranges as input and it prints the count of number of every possible intersection of  range excluding the intersection with itself.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using a `range` to represent your overlapping intervals. It would be much easier to understand your `if` statement if you did a `<` comparison be tween the max and the min, rather than building a `range` and testing it for truthiness.